# Not receiving shiprocket webhook events

Tags: shiprocket

When I test the webhook_url in the shiprocket dashboard then I get the event properly. But I am not getting any events for actual orders.
https://www.shiprocket.in/

Comment: Can you please share your code? What did you try so far?

Comment: Same thing is happening with me as well, I am also not getting any webhook events from shiprocket. Testing endpoint on shiprocket webhooks settings is working fine. That means endpoint is valid and working fine.